# When saving .xlsm file in EPPlus 4.05, I get an error and then Excel deletes /xl/vbaProject.bin part

Tags: .net-core, epplus

I get an error when I try the following code:

```
       //https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/31
        //Otherwise, I get an EPP error
        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
        //var excelFile = new FileInfo($"{keywordLocation.FilePath}{keywordLocation.FileName}".Replace("http://", ""));
        var excelFile = new FileInfo(@"wwwroot/SubmissionFiles/23477-1/Financial_Report_0001091596.xlsx");
        using (var source = new ExcelPackage(excelFile))
        {
            //source.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("VBA Sample");
            source.Workbook.CreateVBAProject();
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("Private Sub Workbook_Open()");
            sb.AppendLine("End Sub");
            source.Workbook.CodeModule.Code = sb.ToString();
            source.SaveAs(new FileInfo(@"wwwroot/SubmissionFiles/23477-1/Financial_Report_0001091596.xlsm"));
        }
```

Here's the error:

[Problem in workbook error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW3BJ.png)

When I click on OK, I get the following error:

[Excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1eQS.png)

I've also tried this with the simplest VBA code consisting of a single comment: `sb.AppendLine("'VBA Code");`

Comment: Here's the file in question: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1091596/000143774917005460/Financial_Report.xlsx.

If anyone can add even the slightest bit of VBA code to it, save it as a .xlsm file and have it open successfully, that would at least indicate the problem is on my end. I tried with very basic VBA code above and when I open the file, Excel says there's a problem and deletes the VBA.bin part.

Comment: Note: I tried this again with Epplus 4.5.0.2 rc, but the results are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current EPPlus 4.5.3.2 still has the same problem...
Don't even have to change the macro content

```
    using (var targetPackage = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filename)))
    {
        var target = targetPackage.Workbook.VbaProject;
...
        targetPackage.Save();
   }
```

and the result is incorrect for Excel 2016.